# How to read grouped bytes using Qt in c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to read a file in which data must grouped by 5 bytes; the following is the routine to read first 5 bytes:

```
QFile myfile("data.dat");
myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in(&myfile);
for (quint8 index = 0; index < 5; index ++)
{
in >> DateListArray[index];
...do something ....
}
```

My problem is: how can I read the rest of file? I have to "jump" to 6 bytes further, at the beginning of every record of 5 bytes.
Hoping it's clear.
Is there someone who can show me how?
Thanks
Paolo

Comment: Is there something in `readBytes()` or `readRawData()` that doesn't make sense? You're using a serialized stream so presumably you have the serialization code that **also** uses QDataStream and you can mirror that.

Comment: @Adrian
readRawData() seems to be a good solution, but it's not clear for me how to do.
At the moment, I solved as follows:
    for (quint8 idx = 0; idx < 32; idx++)
    {
    for (index[idx] = 0; index[idx] < 5; index[idx] ++)
    {
    in >> DateListArray[index[idx]];
    ... read the file contains 5 bytes, separate them and place on their own destination
    ...
    }
    }
If you could send me an explained example, I'll try.
Thanks
Paolo